# observer on a collection

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I am taking my first steps in Rx frameworks on .net 4.
i am trying to observe a collection like `List<int>` or `Dictionary<x,x>`.
and when a item is added to the collection it will write it `ToString()` in the console.

any ideas ? or some code samples 
thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`List<T>` and `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` are not observable (they do not raise events when they change), so there is nothing for Rx to hook into.

For `List`, you can use [`ObservableCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx), but you would need to wrap its events to use it from Rx. Here is an example using extension methods:

```
public static class ObservableCollectionExtensions
{
    public static IObservable<IEvent<NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs>> 
        GetObservableChanges<T>(this ObservableCollection<T> collection)
    {
        return Observable.FromEvent<
            NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler, NotifyCollectionChangedArgs>(
                h => new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(h),
                h => collection.CollectionChanged += h,
                h => collection.CollectionChanged -= h
            );
    }

    public static IObservable<T> GetObservableAddedValues<T>(
        this ObservableCollection<T> collection)
    {
        return collection.GetObservableChanges()
            .Where(evnt => evnt.EventArgs.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
            .SelectMany(evnt => evnt.EventArgs.NewItems.Cast<T>());
    }
}
```

I've included an additional helper that only exposes the newly added items as an `IObservable<T>`, which you can use like this:

```
ObservableCollection<int> collection = 
    new ObservableCollection<int>(new int[] { 1, 2, 3 });

collection.GetObservableAddedValues().Subscribe(
    i => Console.WriteLine("{0} was added", i)
);
```

There is no observable Dictionary in the framework, though the [ObservableDictionary codeplex project](http://observabledictionary.codeplex.com/) appears to fill that gap and I'm sure it could be wrapped in a similar way.

Answer (score 1):

For those who do not have the option to use the `IEvent` interface using `FromEventPattern` can be used instead:

```
public static class ObservableCollectionExtensions
{
    public static IObservable<EventPattern<NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs>>
    GetObservableChanges<T>(this ObservableCollection<T> collection)
    {
        return Observable.FromEventPattern<
            NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs>(
                h => collection.CollectionChanged += h,
                h => collection.CollectionChanged -= h
            );
    }

    public static IObservable<T> GetObservableAddedValues<T>(
        this ObservableCollection<T> collection)
    {
        return collection.GetObservableChanges()
            .Where(evnt => evnt.EventArgs.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
            .SelectMany(evnt => evnt.EventArgs.NewItems.Cast<T>());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ReactiveCollection` from [ReactiveUI](http://www.reactiveui.net/):

```
var c = new ReactiveCollection<int>();
c.Changed.Subscribe(x => Console.Writeln(x.Value);
c.Add(1);
```

Comment: have you tried it ? and why not using observbleCollection instead ?